# Quick question: Direct sum of zero-dimensional subschemes supported at the same point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, schemes

For a torsion free sheaf $E$ on a surface $X$ we have

$0\rightarrow E\rightarrow E^{**}\rightarrow Z\rightarrow 0$

where $Z$ is a zero dimensional subscheme of $X$.

Let $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$ be a closed point. Let $\mathcal{I}_p$ be the corresponding ideal sheaf.

> We have $(\mathcal{I}_p^{\oplus 2})^{**}=\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}$. Hence $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}/\mathcal{I}_p^{\oplus 2}$ is a zero dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2$.
>
> But $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}/\mathcal{I}_p^{\oplus 2}=\mathcal{O}_p^{\oplus 2}$ - not a subscheme. Where did this go wrong?

Comment: $Z$ is not necessary a subscheme, it is just a sheaf with zero-dimensional support. And your example just shows this.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should delete this post since it is kinda silly?

Comment: No, you may keep your post: it's not silly. But you could improve it by not confusing terminologically sheaves and subschemes, as you just did with $Z$.