# Quick question: Confusion on Quot scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, schemes

This is a followup of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888959/quick-question-direct-sum-of-zero-dimensional-subschemes-supported-at-the-same).

Let $p$ be a point on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

I still have a question. Is the quotient $(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}^{\oplus 2}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}_p^{\oplus 2})$ in $\mathrm{Quot}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}^2,1)$ or $\mathrm{Quot}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}^2,2)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal O_p$?

Comment: Sorry! It's just a point on the plane. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2, p}$ or the residue field of this?

Comment: Forgive me: How is that a quotient?

Comment: I was being stupid, of course it is the residue field at $p$. I'd better write it as $\mathbb{C}_p$. Sorry!

Comment: Okay, then you just need to calculate the Hilbert polynomial and it seems like that's definitely $2$.